# Does my use case be implemented using Esper CEP

Tags: messaging, complex-event-processing, esper

For the requirements of my project, I have been suggested to use User Esper CEP engine. However, after going through some documentation of Esper, I don't think, it suits to my use case. Can anybody explain how Esper can be used given the below requirements?
- There is a queue of applications exists
- The initiator application sends a JMS messages to next system/application and it sends it to next system in turn. This continues till some final system which finally sends the ack which traverses the reverse way till the initiator system. 
- Each of the systems while sending message to the next system in the queue sends a copy of the message to my application. Similarly a copy of ack from each system is also received in the return way by my system.
- Each message from a system is related to the message generated by its previous system and so is the ack.
- The requirement of my system is to link all these messages and their acks using the linkage information in the messages and find if any message is missed or nor received.
- Likewise there can be thousands of source messages and its related messages received in the system
- Each message hierarchy has a unique id
- My system can receive the messages in any arbitrary order/sequence

Can anybody help me to understand how Esper can be used to link the messages and find the missing messages in each message hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Esper makes it easy to detect absence of events, such as via pattern or outer join, or presence of abnormal flow. Samples can be found in http://esper.codehaus.org/tutorials/solution_patterns/solution_patterns.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I went through the link. However, not sure if I am missing something, still i do not find the CEP approach much useful for my use case.  In my requirement, one order message can be followed by n number of fill messages. And there can be millions of orders each having a uniqueId. In addition, each order message has multiple related order messages. How would I keep track of the missing orders or fills in each order hierarchy?